# How to manually set and lose focus of a TextBox in WinRT Windows 8

Tags: textbox, windows-8, windows-runtime, lost-focus

I have a Textbox and on the `LostFocus` event of it, I have a function called `SaveWeight()` to save the value based on few conditions. I need to programatically trigger that function.

For example, I have a `OnClearButClicked` function in which the the value in the textbox is cleared. So after it is cleared, I need to call the `SaveWeight` function. But since it is a LostFocus event I need to manually set the focus of the textbox to `Unfocused` which might hopefully trigger the `SaveWeight()`.

```
private void OnClearButClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    weightTBox.Text = "";
    weightTBox.Focus(Windows.UI.Xaml.FocusState.Unfocused);
}
```

But the `weightTBox.Focus(Windows.UI.Xaml.FocusState.Unfocused);` throws an `ArgumentException`. So is my approach wrong? Can I set the `FocusState` for an element and then trigger the event. Or some other thing I'm missing?

Comment: Properly you have to give a other element the focus. Just removing is a problem because windows does not know which element should now get the focus.

Comment: Nope that still gives the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just call the method, passing in null as the arguments?

```
SaveWeight(null, null);
```

It seems to me, setting focus in the UI is a huge violation of the separation of concerns in your code base.

Comment: Oh, I did not know this. I thought since it is `private void SaveWeight(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)` it needs to be triggered only on LostFocus event. Thanks a lot!!!!